# Excel Row Count Per Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently using the code below to count all the rows in each sheet and it prints on the main sheet of the workbook. Now, I'm trying to print the amount of rows used on each sheet in the last row of that specific sheet and on the main sheet as well.

```
    Function Test_It()
    Dim printRow As Integer
    printRow = 2
    For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        Range("N" & printRow).Value = "Sheet Name:"
        Range("O" & printRow).Value = Sheet.Name
        Range("P" & printRow).Value = "Count:"
        Range("Q" & printRow).Value = CountMyRows(Sheet.Name)
        printRow = printRow + 1
    Next Sheet
End Function


Function CountMyRows(SName As String) As Long         '# where SName is the name of a sheet
    Dim RowCount As Long
    RowCount = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SName).UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1
    CountMyRows = RowCount
End Function
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

---

Code that didn't work

```
Sub LineCount()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim RowCount As Integer
    Dim countTotal As Long
    Dim myArray() As Variant

    RowCount= ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    countTotal = RowCount
    ReDim myArray(1 To RowCount)

    For i = 1 To RowCount
        countTotal = ""
        myArray(1) = Worksheets(i).UsedRange.Rows.Count
        Debug.Print myArray(1)
        Range("A" & countTotal).Value = countTotal
    Next


End Sub
```

---

This is the goal:

Main sheet:
[image: this is the main sheet where all the rows used reside]

Sheet 2:
[image: sheet 2 contains other related data]

Sheet 3:
[image: sheet 3 contains other related data]

Sheet 4:
[image: sheet 4 contains other related data]

---

Final code I got to work

```
Sub LineCount()

Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    dict(sht.Name) = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    sht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0) = "Rows Used: " & dict(sht.Name)
Next sht

With Sheet1
    .Range("A1").Resize(dict.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.Keys)
    .Range("B1").Resize(dict.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.Items)
End With


End Sub
```

The only issue now is that when the button is pressed multiple times, it will recount the rows from 14 rows to now 28 rows and so on (depending on how many times the button is pressed). How could this be resolved?

Comment: What is your exact question?  What error/issue are you having converting your previous code to your new intent?  if not currently presented, please state what you've tried, and give examples where applicable.

Comment: There are [better ways to count rows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11169445/9758194)

Comment: print amount of rows used on each sheet @Cyril

Comment: `LastRow = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count` - is this actually what you have? That is a confusing variable name for a worksheet count. Also you can't do `countTotal = " "` if `countTotal` is a `Long`.

Comment: @BigBen - yes, the code is copied directly from VBA editor.

Comment: Well please fix that naming then - for our sanity and yours :-)

Comment: please see the added images for the goal

Answer (score 0):

Something fairly basic could be:

```
Sub Test()

Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    dict(sht.Name) = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Next sht

With Sheet1
    .Range("A2").Resize(dict.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.Keys)
    .Range("B2").Resize(dict.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.Items)
End With

End Sub
```

Implement an `If` condition on the `sht.Name` property if you want to avoid including the "Main" sheet, whichever that is in your case.

Comment: This code works but it prints the sheet name on only sheet1, I need it on all the sheets + 1 row from the last row used. Like on sheet 2-4 in the images where it says "row used: x". How could that be added?

Comment: Then you'll have to adjust the code within the for each sht loop to include that. It now shows you how to get the last used row =)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a UDF.

```
Public Function RowCount(Optional ShtRef As Range) As Long

    Application.Volatile

    Dim Ref As Range

    If ShtRef Is Nothing Then
        Set Ref = Application.Caller
    Else
        Set Ref = ShtRef
    End If

    With Ref
        If ShtRef Is Nothing Then
            RowCount = .End(xlUp).Row 'Last row above where formula is called from.
        Else
            RowCount = .Parent.Cells(.Parent.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'All rows on referenced sheet.
        End If
    End With

End Function
```

Now the formula `=RowCount()` will return the last row in column A above where you typed the formula, while `=RowCount(Sheet2!$A$1)` will return the total row count on Sheet2.

Not perfect as it would include your `Rows Used` when looking at other sheets, so not expecting an accepted answer from it - just for info really.

Answer (score 0):

Sub CountRowsAndSummarize()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim SummaryWs As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim WorksheetName As String

```
' Set the summary worksheet (Sheet_1)
On Error Resume Next
Set SummaryWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet_1")
On Error GoTo 0

' If the summary worksheet doesn't exist, create it
If SummaryWs Is Nothing Then
    Set SummaryWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
    SummaryWs.Name = "Sheet_1"
End If

' Initialize the row counter on the summary sheet
SummaryWs.Cells.Clear
SummaryWs.Range("A1").Value = "Worksheet Name"
SummaryWs.Range("B1").Value = "Number of Rows"

' Loop through all worksheets except the summary sheet
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Sheet_1" Then
        WorksheetName = ws.Name
        ' Find the last used row in the current worksheet
        LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        ' Write the worksheet name and row count to the summary sheet
        SummaryWs.Cells(SummaryWs.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1).Value = WorksheetName
        SummaryWs.Cells(SummaryWs.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1, 2).Value = LastRow
    End If
Next ws
```

End Sub

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).